# Writing a generic iterator in Java

Tags: java, generics, iterator, abstract-class, ienumerable

I was getting out of memory exceptions when I stored a collection of my class `AbstractState` in memory, so I am trying to write an iterable/iterator. I have a bit of C# knowledge but little Java experience. In C# I would write a method returning an `IEnumerable<AbstractState>`, but it doesn't seem so easy here.

`AbstractState` stores a pair of coordinates, although depending on the implementation, the operations on them differ. (It also extends a generic `MyPair<Coordinate>`.)

Within `AbstractState`, I define a constructor `AbstractState(Coordinate A, Coordinate B){super(A,B);}`. I override this in some but not all sub-classes. `Coordinate` is concrete. Here is my iterable:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class StateSpace<T extends AbstractState> implements Iterable<T> {
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new StateIterator();
    }
}
```

and my Iterator:

```
public class StateIterator<T extends AbstractState> implements Iterator<T> {
    private Iterator<Coordinate> iX, iY;

    StateIterator(){
        iX = Main.GRID.iterator();
        iY = Main.GRID.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iX.hasNext() || iY.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

(`GRID` here is a static range of `Coordinate`s.)

How can I implement the `next()` method correctly? (Or, what is a better design for my code to solve this problem?)

---

Instantiating a `T` does not work, and I cannot instantiate an abstract class. I think I was close by trying

```
getDeclaredConstructor(Coordinate.class, Coordinate.class).newInstance(iX.next(), iY.next());
```

but I got a compiler warning for no such method.

I had unchecked casts when I casted to a `T`, so suspect that this is a bad idea. Having many iterators/iterables is unappealing, as I would be checking (via `if` statements or a `switch`) which iterator I need, which undermines my OO code design.

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "when I stored a collection of my class AbstractState in memory"? Please clarify: Do you already have a collection of AbstractState in memory and you get a memory exception when you add to it? in that case iterating it won't help you.

Comment: @inor sorry - just saw this. Previously I created the collection of AbstractState to be used later (in for loops). I could not even create it because it was too large. So I would like to iterate through an iterable so that storing every AbstractState in memory is not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `this` to the iterator constructor. The StateSpace has access to the instantiated `T` type, and so it can implement methods to determine how to `getNext()` and `hasNext()`. It's not clear what `iX` and `iY` are about.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class StateSpace<T extends AbstractState> implements Iterable<T> {
    List<T> types;
    int pos;

    public StateSpace() {
        types = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void add(T type) {
        types.add(type);
    }
    T getNext() {
        return types.get(pos++);
    }
    boolean hasNext() {
         return pos < types.size()-1;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new StateIterator(this);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class StateIterator<T extends AbstractState> implements Iterator<T> {
    private Iterator<Coordinate> iX, iY;
    private StateSpace<T> stateSpace;

    StateIterator(StateSpace<T> stateSpace){
        this.stateSpace = stateSpace;
        iX = Main.GRID.iterator();
        iY = Main.GRID.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iX.hasNext() || iY.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        return stateSpace.getNext(); // or whatever.
    }
}
```

maybe helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. `next()` must return a `T`, but `stateSpace` is of type `StateSpace<T>`. I tried putting a method in `StateSpace` that returns a `T`, but have the same problems

Comment: Right, sorry, assuming StateSpace saves or has access to a type T then stateSpace should be able to getNext(); Updated.

Comment: Ahaa, that makes sense: if you can't getNext then it isn't "Iterable" really. I'll need to keep track of the current AbstractSpace so I can iterate to the next